# How to Update source code program by RFC?

Tags: abap

is ther any FM to change the source code program by RFC? like RPY_PROGRAM_UPDATE?

in standard in rfc we have RPY_PROGRAM_INSERT/ READ but UPDATE is not in rfc

does anyone know any module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that we have **RPY_PROGRAM_UPDATE** function module but it doesn't remote enabled function. Maybe it is fixed for different versions.
Alternatively you can use **RPY_INCLUDE_UPDATE** function module for updating programs.

Answer (score 3):

Due to the potential risk of cyber attacks, it's very risky to create programs dynamically from outside.

You should never use standard programs which are not released. `RPY_PROGRAM_INSERT`,  `RPY_PROGRAM_UPDATE` are not released.

Better create your own very secure code, with authorization checks plus as many checks as possible, because companies not always master the authorizations they give. Don't use the ABAP statement `INSERT REPORT` as it's reserved to SAP. Only `GENERATE SUBROUTINE POOL` could be used productively but be careful of limits (36 times max by internal session).

See the ABAP documentation for `INSERT REPORT` (reserved to SAP) and `GENERATE SUBROUTINE POOL` (can be used but with limits).

PS: personally, I would never permit this kind of code in my system.

Comment: yes, i know but i create a abap ide to my onw purposes, i work on such an old version (4.5B) of sap and i want to improve my own work only :)